# JQuery bug, slidetoggle() function stacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a weird problem with the `slideToggle()` jQuery function. I don't know what I'm breaking (nor repairing), but sometimes on hover it displays the divs that are normally hidden and sometimes stacks up so that the whole div gets bigger and bigger. I was able to copy the previous jQuery code before and repair it, but now it does nothing. I have a few jQuery codes embedded in my divs so that few of them stay open on hover.

The code looks like that:

```
$("#colorstoggle").hover(function(e) {
    $("#red").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#yellow").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#blue").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#green").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#purple").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
})

$("#red").hover(function(e) {
    $("#red").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    $("#yellow").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    $("#blue").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    $("#green").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
    $("#purple").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
})
```

And so on...

The html is a list:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item" id="str1but">Podsumowanie</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="str2but">Dane</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="str3but">Wykres</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="str4but">Autorzy</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="colorstoggle">
    Kolor:</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="yellow" style="color:yellow">kolor żółty</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="blue" style="color:blue">kolor niebieski</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="red" style="color:red">kolor czerwony</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="purple" style="color:purple">kolor fioletowy</li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="green" style="color:green">kolor zielony</li>
</ul>
```

And the nav-item class is:

```
.nav-item {
    width: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.7em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zcw87ya/1/) of your code running, with the background of the `ul` showing to demonstrate the expanding `div`.

It's normal that the parent element expands, as by default, HTML block level elements will expand to accommodate the elements within. In this case, the `li`'s are expanding/contracting, so the `ul` expands/contracts with it.

**The code**

It's hard to offer specific help, as it's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your code. There are a few things you might consider though:

- It looks like you are potentially complicating things by offering 2 controls to do the same thing (slideToggle the same set of elements) and one control (`#red`) is a target element of the first (`#colorstoggle`).
- It also looks like you are referencing the colour `li` items as children of `#colorstoggle`, so you could consider using a *nested list* to contain these elements separately and reduce confusion. **Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/88qLke3u/)**.
- You can also cull the amount of repeated code used by grouping your jQuery selectors.

**[Using multiple selectors in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

```
$("#colorstoggle").hover(function(e) {
    $("#red").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#yellow").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#blue").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#green").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
    $("#purple").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
})
```

Can be reduced into:

```
$("#colorstoggle").hover(function(e) {
  $("#red, #yellow, #blue, #green, #purple").stop(true, false).slideToggle(200);
})
```